# How to create a Google Apps Script that auto expire Shared Link Folder with People in custom minutes?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have a folder in Google Drive that I want to shared with my fellows.
The use-case here is that I want the Link I share auto expire after 5 minutes (or I can custom my minutes).
I've found google this link http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-expire-google-drive-links/27509/ but it's not what I need.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/19760-google-drive-sharing-permissions) on how to set auto-expiration dates for shared links and makes the folder /file “Private” after the expiration date.

```
var EXPIRY_TIME  = "2014-05-01 23:42"; 

function autoExpire() {

  var id, asset, i, email, users;     
  // The URL of the Google Drive file or folder 
  var URL = "https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4fk8L6brI_ednJaa052";

  try {        
    // Extract the File or Folder ID from the Drive URL
    var id = URL.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);

    if (id) {          
      asset = DriveApp.getFileById(id) ? DriveApp.getFileById(id) : DriveApp.getFolderById(id);          
      if (asset) {            
        // Make the folder / file Private 
        asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);  
        asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);             
        // Remove all users who have edit permissions
        users = asset.getEditors();
        for (i in users) {
          email = users[i].getEmail();
          if (email != "") {
            asset.removeEditor(email);
          }
        }            
        // Remove all users who have view permssions
        users = asset.getViewers();
        for (i in users) {
          email = users[i].getEmail();
          if (email != "") {
            asset.removeViewer(email);
          }
        }              
      }
    }      
  } catch (e) {        
    Logger.log(e.toString());        
  }
}

function Start() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i in triggers) {        
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);        
  }

  var time = EXPIRY_TIME;      
  // Run the auto-expiry script at this date and time     
  var expireAt = new Date(time.substr(0,4),
                          time.substr(5,2)-1,
                          time.substr(8,2),
                          time.substr(11,2),
                          time.substr(14,2));

  if ( !isNaN ( expireAt.getTime() ) ) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("autoExpire").timeBased().at(expireAt).create();
  }     
}
```

The script will run at the specific time and remove all the sharing permissions from your file or folder making them private and the shared links would no longer work. You can also check this [blog](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/expiration-date-google-drive-folders/).

Comment: Thank you #abielita, I am not a coder so it's really hard for me to understand this script. Please play a demo for me, for example the link will be expired every 5 minutes? (In the other words, after 5 minutes, every user have the permission must be revoked.